# sublime text 2: auto format php?

Tags: sublime-text-2

Is there a plugin that can format and indent PHP automatically with sublime text 2?

I'm really used to aptana and have taken for granted the ctrl + alt + f.

Comment: Found this just now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628372/is-it-possible-to-auto-format-php-in-sublime-text-2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [SublimePhPTidy](https://github.com/welovewordpress/SublimePhpTidy)?

This uses Wordpress coding standards.

In addition, in the package listings:

- [PHPcs](http://soulbroken.co.uk/code/sublimephpcs)
- [PHPtidy](https://github.com/welovewordpress/SublimePhpTidy)
- [PHPBeautifier](https://github.com/SublimeText/PhpBeautifier)

ZenCoding, Sublime Lint and Sublime CodeIntel may also be of use.

Comment: No i haven't. but i'm not sure if i'd like to use wordpress stnadards. The other packages seem interesting Thanks!